# How to infer type correctly based on another type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to infer the type of `tab` object to `{leftText: string, rightText?: string}` type when `props.group` is `true`, to `{title: string}` type when `props.group` is `false`.

```
type ButtonTab =
  | {
      leftText: string;
      rightText?: string;
    }
  | { title: string };

interface ButtonTabsProps {
  tabsList: ButtonTab[];
  group?: boolean;
}

function ButtonTabs(props: Readonly<ButtonTabsProps>) {
    return props.tabsList.map((tab: ButtonTab) => {
        if(props.group) {
            return `${tab.leftText} ${tab.rightText}`
        }
        return `${tab.title}`
    })
}
```

For now, TSC throw an error:

> Property 'leftText' does not exist on type 'ButtonTab'.
> Property 'leftText' does not exist on type '{ title: string; }'.

code: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=19&pln=11&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrsYB7AdgFQIYCMoF4CwAUFFAD5QDeRJNUANhAGbBoQAewAXFAM7ABOASxQBzANzVaUISIAWLdsAD83PkNETiNAL6TyFKMEHAGqgcJFRtmosOAR+jDAGNo8RKkxYeABX5IwHkpJYGweABlBPm53ZHRsAG0AXU0SEX84MBUoLCQkBgwUTV1CIkY4FGcjVFgEOK8eAAowf0DuACUIDAATVDoQAB5YzzC-AJ4APgBKYK0SfghgOH4UKBbxgDpQ70i+DYBbDDBGxu2YupGsGdwJ2akaQUZm1p4N9KRMmao5+5oFpZWUAABgASCjbDYMZisDjaKBgiEyeQw4DaIGSe4lX7SRbLVag8HYLbGBhojFWKZEbRAA)

Comment: Sounds like you want `ButtonTabsProps` to be a union type, instead of `ButtonTab`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the `props.group` prop there are no related with `ButtonTab` type.

And `props.group` should be moving out.

```
type ButtonTab<G extends boolean = true> = G extends true
  ? {
      leftText: string;
      rightText?: string;
    }
  : {title: string};

type ButtonTabsProps =
  | {
      tabsList: ButtonTab<true>[];
      group: true;
    }
  | {
      tabsList: ButtonTab<false>[];
      group: false;
    };

function ButtonTabs(props: ButtonTabsProps) {
  if (props.group) {
    return props.tabsList.map(tab => {
      return `${tab.leftText} ${tab.rightText}`;
    });
  }

  return props.tabsList.map(tab => {
    return `${tab.title}`;
  });
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrsYB7AdgFQIYCMA8BxKCAD2AhQBMBnKLJJAGwgxSgF4pgAnOCAPjagFipCtS48AsACgoUAPxQA3tNmqojAGbA0wgFxRKXAJYoA5gG4VaqJyOmAFtuFz9h22cszVAXyv7FwEbAjK7GZt6e0qCQsAjI6NiUAAqcSGDUrFYAPkpWasCJADJGhvrwiKiYuOJ8ANoAup7WUKapcGD6NU0%202ble%20UUlwGVxldg4Ghj0lHWNeaqtSO36k9MQ3bIR0tIacCgAxoGosRUJWJQAFGCp6SOnVck3lACUfbJGGlBXTwB0i%202vZT9GwQYBwTgsa5pSg-ArnYqGH4AWwwYAucLY-CBzU4oPBLAABgASALYH6aJwkbxQElwn62ByU4DeAkbKDeZ7dXxSKy4sEQqBQ9KwwaIlFojGsLHzPn4qDE0lYWFBRgsrmc6TeIA)

Answer (score 0):

```
interface ButtonTabText {
  leftText: string
  rightText?: string
}
interface ButtonTabTitle {
  title: string
}

interface ButtonTabsText {
  group: true
  tabsList: ButtonTabText[]
}
interface ButtonTabsTitle {
  group: false
  tabsList: ButtonTabTitle[]
}

type Props = ButtonTabsTitle | ButtonTabsText

const renderTabsText = (tabsList: ButtonTabText[]): string[] =>
  tabsList.map((tab) => `${tab.leftText} ${tab.rightText}`)

const renderTabsTitle = (tabsList: ButtonTabTitle[]): string[] =>
  tabsList.map((tab) => tab.title)

function ButtonTabs(props: Readonly<Props>) {
  return props.group
    ? renderTabsText(props.tabsList)
    : renderTabsTitle(props.tabsList)
}
```